# ¿Como implementar con sequelize dos relaciones a una misma tabla(games) que proviene de la tabla (multimedia)?

Tags: mysql, nodejs, sequelize

Mi duda esta en como implemento con sequelize esta relación he buscado en varios sitios y no encuentro una respuesta que me pueda ayudar, adjunto con una imagen con lo que necesito

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la tengo creada como muestro en el código a continuación:

```
games.js 

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Game = sequelize.define("Game", {
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        }

    });

    Game.associate = models => {
        Game.hasMany(models.Lesson, {
            onDelete: "cascade"
        });

        Game.hasMany(models.Games_theme, {
            onDelete: "cascade"
        });

        Game.belongsTo(models.Multimedia, {
                foreignkey: {
                    name: "MultimediaId_audio",
                    allowNull: false
                },
                foreignkey: {
                    name: "MultimediaId_img",
                    allowNull: true
                }
        });
    };
    return Game;
};
```

Esto fue lo que realice pero no funciona con este codigo simplemente creo una relación pero la otra no . Agradezco su ayuda

Comment: Ayudaría mucho entender por que esa relación, ¿segur@ que esta correcta?

Comment: Coincido con @BetaM, la realción sobre el campo `name` no la veo clara. Un registro de la tabla `games` se relaciona mediante `name` con un registro de la tabla `multimedia`. Eso da a entender que cada entidad `game` se llama igual que una entidad `multimedia` y viceversa. Eso se traduce a que `Pacman` puede ser el nombre de un tipo multimedia, y a su vez `Audio` puede ser el nombre de un juego. No le veo mucho sentido. Saludos

Comment: Hola si es necesaria esta relación ya que en  mi tabla multimedia se encuentra almacenado una serie de rutas de imagenes y audios las cuales necesito en mi tabla Games. la tabla multimedia almacena la información segun el tipo, y en algunos juegos desarrollados necesitas ambas en otras no dependiendo del contexto del juego. Pero si es necesaria la relacion cualquier ayuda estare atenta.